# How can I know how many element with specific background-color?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table. When I clicked on a td it will add background color to that td, the color depends on radio button checked, then it will count how many td that has xxx background color.

You can have a look at demo on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hyNMN/3/). You must checked a radio button first.

This is my JS.

```
var method1 = 0;
var method2 = 0;
var method3 = 0;
var method4 = 0;
var method5 = 0;
var clickedTeeth;

$('td').click(function(){
    if($('input[type=radio]').is(':checked')) {
            var clickingTeeth = $(this).attr('id');
            if(clickedTeeth == clickingTeeth) {

        } else {
            clickedTeeth = clickingTeeth;
            var color;
            var value = $("input:radio:checked").val();
            value = parseInt(value);
            switch(value){
                case 1:
                    color = 'red';
                    break;
                case 2:
                    color = 'blue';
                    break;
                case 3:
                    color = 'green';
                    break;
                case 4:
                    color = 'yellow';
                    break;
                case 5:
                    color = 'purple';
                    break;
            }
            $(this).css('background-color',color);
            updateResult();
        }

} else {
    alert('You must check radio button first');
}
});

function updateResult(){
    $('td').each(function(){
        if($(this).css('background-color') == 'red'){
            method1++;
        }
        if($(this).css('background-color') == 'blue'){
            method2++;
        }
        if($(this).css('background-color') == 'green'){
            method3++;
        }
        if($(this).css('background-color') == 'yellow'){
            method4++;
        }
        if($(this).css('background-color') == 'purple'){
            method5++;
        }
    });
    alert(method1); // Alert amount of red here.
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: `css('background-color')` returns values in RGB format `rgb(0, 0, 255)` so your comparisons won't work.

Comment: What about in hexadecimal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case :

```
var method1 = 0;
var method2 = 0;
var method3 = 0;
var method4 = 0;
var method5 = 0;
var clickedTeeth;

$('td').click(function(){
   if($('input[type=radio]').is(':checked')) {
        var clickingTeeth = $(this).attr('id');
        if(clickedTeeth == clickingTeeth) {

        } else {
            clickedTeeth = clickingTeeth;
            var color;
            var value = $("input:radio:checked").val();
            value = parseInt(value);
            switch(value){
                case 1:
                    color = 'red';
                    updateResult(++method1);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    color = 'blue';
                    updateResult(++method2);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    color = 'green';
                    updateResult(++method3);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    color = 'yellow';
                    updateResult(++method4);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    color = 'purple';
                    updateResult(++method5);
                    break;
            }
            $(this).css('background-color',color);
        }

  } else {
    alert('You must check radio button first');
  }
});

function updateResult(method){
 alert(method); // Alert amount of red here.
}
```